# Desktop background goes crazy at startup

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, xfce

Why does my Xubuntu desktop background looks like this at startup?

[image]

It happens for a few seconds and then displays a normal background image.
The issue began after I switched the graphics card driver from generic to Nvidia. But when I returned back to generic drivers (X.org X Server), the problem was still there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to `Settings > Session and Startup > Splash` and then test one of the several splashes available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've tried what you said and the problem persists.